# r bar of sum of column x by groups in column y

Tags: r, ggplot2

HI I have a data frame with census tract data including (in columns) total population, population at ages 0-14, 15-29, 30-65, 65 and up. In addition, I have for each tract (i.e., row) air pollution levels for three pollutants (NO2, PM25, O3). Here is the str:

```
> str(Pop_2015_Exposure)
'data.frame':   3128 obs. of  13 variables:
$ OBJECTID : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ age_0_14 : int  260 120 160 170 110 210 240 260 30 270 ...
$ age_15_19: int  70 50 30 50 20 50 40 60 200 20 ...
$ age_20_29: int  80 80 50 50 30 40 80 20 40 60 ...
$ age_30_64: int  320 170 210 210 150 230 310 260 100 200 ...
$ age_65_up: int  100 50 60 70 50 50 60 10 20 20 ...
$ NO2_ugm3 : num  11.16 8.28 10.75 3.29 11.93 ...
$ NOx_ugm3 : num  14.3 10 13.8 4.3 15 ...
$ O3_ugm3  : num  65.9 71 66.3 88.1 66.6 ...
$ CO_ugm3  : num  124 126 123 106 121 ...
$ SO2_ugm3 : num  4.187 1.947 4.208 0.449 10.211 ...
$ PM10_ugm3: num  39.6 39.7 39.6 37.6 41.9 ...
$ PM25_ugm3: num  18.2 17.8 18.2 16.1 20.3 ...
```

I need to plot for each age group (and the total population) the number of people that are exposed to levels of pollution (e.g., PM25_ugm3)  between 10%,20%,...,100% , >100% of a limit value (e.g., 40 ug/m3 for PM25). First I created a factor variable with the groups of pollution levels by:

```
PM25_Limit = 40
Perc_ranges = seq(0,100,10)
PM25_ranges = PM25_Limit * Perc_ranges/100
Pop_2015_Exposure$PM25_Perc = cut(Pop_2015_Exposure$PM25_ugm3, PM25_ranges,right = TRUE)
```

Now, I want to plot a stacked bar plot for PM25_ugm3 where each column will be an age group and the stacks will be the number of people exposed to PM25 for each pollution range (PM25_Perc). Here is some dummy data:

```
Pop_Tracts = data.frame(OBJECTID = seq(1,100),
                        age_0_14 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_15_19 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_20_29 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_30_64 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_65_up = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        PM25_ugm3 = 100*runif(n = 100))

PM25_Limit = 40
Perc_ranges = seq(0,100,10)
PM25_ranges = PM25_Limit * Perc_ranges/100
Pop_Tracts$PM25_Perc = cut(Pop_Tracts$PM25_ugm3, PM25_ranges,right = TRUE)
```

Thanks

Comment: How can i get the number of exposed people of `age_0_14`?

Comment: by summing the value of age_0_14. Each row holds the population data per one census tract (number of people for each age group) and pollution levels. what I need is to show how many people at the ages of 0-14 are exposed to each percentile (PM25_Perc) of pollution level.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that something seems to have gone wrong with your `PM25_Perc` calculation; there are a lot of `NA`s. If you update your data I'll update my answer.**

Generally, it sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
Pop_Tracts %>%
    gather(age_group, value, starts_with("age_")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(age_group, PM25_ugm3, fill = PM25_Perc)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

---

The `NA`s are a result of the `PM25_Limit = 40` limit, which is too low and prevents binning of `PM25_ugm3` values `>=40`; we can fix this by changing `PM25_Limit` which in turn changes the breaks used in `cut`

```
PM25_Limit = pretty(max(Pop_Tracts$PM25_ugm3))[2]
Perc_ranges = seq(0,100,10)
PM25_ranges = PM25_Limit * Perc_ranges/100
Pop_Tracts$PM25_Perc = cut(Pop_Tracts$PM25_ugm3, PM25_ranges,right = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
Pop_Tracts %>%
    gather(age_group, value, starts_with("age_")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(age_group, PM25_ugm3, fill = PM25_Perc)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is OK for the NA's to be there. It is expected that the pollution levels are lower or higher than the limit value, so not all percentiles of the range (zero-limit) are populated. Are you sure, though, that the bars count the population in each group? knowing the data I am expecting different population sizes in each pollution category and age group (i.e., different number of people exposed to (50,60] at ages 30-64 than 0-14). The question was: _"...each column will be an age group and the stacks will be the number of people exposed to PM25 for each pollution range (PM25_Perc)"_

Comment: @Ilik I'm not sure I understand; just to be clear, I'm not calculating anything. According to your post "*the stacks will be the number of people exposed to PM25 for each pollution range (PM25_Perc)*", so that's what the stacked bars denote (`PM25_Perc`) as per your calculation.

Comment: Evans I'm only a begginer

Comment: I'm only a beginner to ggplot, but as I understand the default behavior in `ggplot(aes(age_group, PM25_ugm3, fill = PM25_Perc))` is to count the occurrences of  PM25_ugm3. What I am after is to sum the population in the age_group. What I want to show is how many people are living at each pollution level (by groups of PM25_Perc). I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @Ilik Ok, I'm not sure I understand your question. It seems to me this is more of a general question (on data summarisation) than one related to `ggplot2`. I thought you were asking how to plot the data, which is what show in my answer. I don't quite understand what you mean by "*sum[ming] the population in the age_group*". From what I understood from your OP (*"I want to plot a stacked bar plot for PM25_ugm3"*) you want to sum the `PM25_ugm3` values per age group. I don't understand what you're trying to do with `PM25_Perc`, but in the plot `PM25_ugm3` values are broken down by that quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Maurits Evers, I figured how to do this:

```
Pop_Tracts = data.frame(OBJECTID = seq(1,100),
                        age_0_14 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_15_19 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_20_29 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_30_64 = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        age_65_up = round(100*runif(n = 100),0),
                        PM25_ugm3 = 100*runif(n = 100))

PM25_Limit = 40
Perc_ranges = seq(0,100,10)
#create breaks:
PM25_ranges = c(PM25_Limit * Perc_ranges/100 , ceiling(max(Pop_Tracts$PM25_ugm3)))
#group values by ranges:
Pop_Tracts$PM25_Perc = cut(Pop_Tracts$PM25_ugm3, PM25_ranges,right = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
#collect columns for age:
Pop_Tracts_g = gather(Pop_Tracts,age_group, value, starts_with("age_"))

library(reshape)
Pop_PM25 = cast(Pop_Tracts_g, PM25_Perc ~ age_group,fun.aggregate = sum)

#calculate percentages:
Pop_PM25_Perc = Pop_PM25
Pop_PM25_Perc[2:6] = sweep((Pop_PM25_Perc[2:6])*100, 2, colSums(Pop_PM25), `/`)

#melt the DF:
Pop_PM25   = melt(Pop_PM25)
Pop_PM25_Perc = melt(Pop_PM25_Perc)

# Sort by PM25_Perc and age_group
Pop_PM25      <- arrange(Pop_PM25     , age_group, desc(PM25_Perc)) 
Pop_PM25_Perc <- arrange(Pop_PM25_Perc, age_group, desc(PM25_Perc)) 

#plot:
ggPop_PM25 =  ggplot(Pop_PM25, aes(x = age_group,y = value,fill = PM25_Perc))
ggPop_PM25   +  geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Pop_PM25") + labs(fill = "PM2.5 (ug/m3)")

ggPop_PM25_Perc = ggplot(Pop_PM25_Perc, aes(x = age_group,y = value, fill = PM25_Perc))
ggPop_PM25_Perc +  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ ggtitle("Pop_PM25_Perc") + labs(fill = "PM2.5 (ug/m3)")
```

[image]

and for the percent:
[image]